# How to parse through a date field using SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I'm using Ruby on Rails, and I have a Users table which has a birthday field that is type date.

What I want to do is be able to show an alert if it is a particular Users birthday. The problem I realized i'm having is that in all my test cases I would make someones birthday today to see if it worked, however if I make someones birthday today but 10 years ago, my alert system stops working because the years do not match.

So basically, I want to get the users birthday, but only the day and month and check to see if it matches todays day and month. Is there some sort of raw query I should be using, or should I be thinking of something else?

Comment: Your birthday field is actually a birthdate field.

Comment: _"using SQL"_ – what database in particular? MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where month(t.dob) = month(curdate()) and day(t.dob) = day(curdate());
```

Note:  most databases support `month()` and `day()`.  All have this functionality but the exact functions might depend on the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy

Comment: Keep in mind that database time and Rails time may differ.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html to get date and month part of datetime

Comment: That's basically a link-only answer. Could you provide a little more details or maybe a code example?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this in a Rails-y fashion by passing your DB's method of extracting month and day into `User.where`.

For instance, to get users born on Feb 14 in SQLite3:

```
User.where("strftime('%m %d', birthday) = ?", "02 14")
```

in MySQL:

```
User.where("month(birthday) = ? AND day(birthday) = ?", "02", "14")`
```

in Postgres:

```
User.where("date_part('month', birthday) = ? AND date_part('day', birthday) = ?", "02", "14")
```

The above snippets assume the column on your `users` table is named `birthday`.